# What's the Esperanto word for "Airbourne"

Tags: single-word-requests

Laŭvorte de ĉina vorto ĝi estus maŝin-kunportata, ĉu ĝi sonas logike en la angla? Mi petas viajn sugestojn. Dankon!

Answer (score 3):

La plej bona vorto, kiu, mi kredas, esprimus preskaŭ ĉiun sencon de la angla vorto "airborne" estas **aerportata**. Tiu vorto esprimas la signifon de "fluganta en la aero" (aerportata aviadilo, aŭ simple fluganta aviadilo), kaj la signifon de "disvastigata de aŭ tra la aero" (aerportata viruso). Tamen oni povus alterne diri simple la vorton **fluganta** se oni parola pri aviadilo. Se oni parolas pri la enhavoj aŭ la pasaĝeroj de la aviadilo, oni povus diri la vorton **enaviadila**

Answer (score 2):

Airborn has two meanings in English. First, is "transmitted by the air". The second is "flying" - as in an airplane getting airborne. It would be helpful if we knew what you were trying to say, but I would suggest ***en la aero*** or ***aera*** depending on context.

- La aviadilo estas en la aero.
- Aeraj malpuraĵoj.